# Spring boot whitelable error page customization

Tags: spring

Help me to understand the below code.  It never redirects to a page called 404.html when an error encounters. I am trying to do a default mapping for /error in spring boot. 
NOTE: Not using any templates

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        container.setPort(9090);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404"));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

It describes how you can handle different HTTP errors, including 404.

Here's something I've used (ErrorResponse is my own custom class).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/error")
public class ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/403")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public ErrorResponse handleForbiddenError() {
        return new ErrorResponse("forbidden", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/404")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ErrorResponse handleNotFound() {
        return new ErrorResponse("not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment Kirill, I think your code might not redirect an /error request to 404.html page i guess. I tried that but did not work. I am not sure if i went wrong in doing that